How to build a native android app using AWS SAM and typescript and kotlin?
I am building my first android app for a uni project which was tasked to make a Native android app using AWS SAM and Node.js/Typscript. I am a bit lost on how to set my repository up and to test/deploy it. Any pointers on where I can start? Thank you.
The resources I found either uses Python or AWS Amplify (which the 'client' don't want).

Well first you go deploy your AWS Sam code first
AWS SAM pretty straight forward.
in this one you will be use NodeJS or javascript or typescript, whatever you prefer.
After that consume the api of what have you deploy using Android kotlin, just like calling rest api or you can test the api first using insomnia or postman.
This is the rough road map i can think of, I know AWS Documentation is so many but the rest is up to you to learn the documentation.
Hope this helpful.

Thank you I will try this out first with my team!
